# what is the differences between promises and async in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-cli, subscription

I don't really understand the differences between the `promise` and the `async pipe` in `angular`

- `async` unsubscribe automatically
- `promise` unsubscribe automatically
- `async` used in template with the `async` pipe
- `promises` used in the typescript file

I might got it wrong so that's why I am asking what is the real difference in `memory`, `performance` etc...

couldn't find a clear answer for that question

Comment: These are all various ways to accomplish the same thing (they could be considered functionally equivalent).

Comment: So they are the same but the only diff is where you use them?

Comment: Where and how as well as if there is an unsubscribe that occurs but that can also depend on the observable being subscribed to and how it was created (httpclient, for example, does not require you to unsubscribe from any returned observables). I would recommend you do some additional research on promises in javascript and if you still have questions ask a more pointed (specific) question as this one is very broad.